# How to have a 128-bits/32 character encryption in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I wanted to encrypt a string from an input using `Encryption Library` in codeigniter, I wanted it to generate a 32 char regardless on how long the input is but the number of character generated from `encrypt()` deters on how many characters the input...

Answer (score 1):

If you could encrypt any string down to 32 characters, 50 gigabyte games and 8K three hour movies could be compressed down to 32 characters. Obviously, that's not possible.

Consider a MD5 or SHA1 hash of the string. It won't be decryptable, and it won't be guaranteed to be unique, but it'll be a fixed, predictable length.

Comment: how about blowfish?

Comment: @Warren No form of reversible encryption can fit an infinite number of characters into a fixed number. It's simply not possible.